# How could I automatically upload files from my directory to server?

Tags: phpstorm, sftp

I am using phpstorm to edit my project on my  computer and on Ctrl-S all changed files uploaded to server. It is very convenient.

But if I add pictures from Photoshop, I need to find them in the folder and uploaded each of them individually.

I think that there is solution that can do this job automatically but can't find it.

Could someone help me?

Comment: See [Automatically upload newly created files to an SFTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28361601/850848).

Comment: please write your comment as an answer to my question so I can accept it

Comment: Accept the duplicate instead.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl How this can be a duplicate if the guy have asked how to do it using PhpStorm?

Comment: @progreccor https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm#SyncchangesandautomaticuploadtoadeploymentserverinPhpStorm-(optional)2.AutomaticUpload -- look at "Upload external changes" option

Comment: @LazyOne this option don't help if I simply add files to folder... Any thoughts about it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl what should I do if need to stop watch the folder?

Comment: To stop, press Ctrl+C.